# Curl: Failed to connect to install.meteor.com port 443 (AWS Server)

Tags: ubuntu, curl, amazon-web-services, meteor, ubuntu-14.04

I am starting a new AWS server to host my personal website. It is running on Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS. I tried to install meteor on the server but the downloading does not go through. I already updated and upgraded the server. I used the following command:

```
curl -v https://install.meteor.com/ | sh
```

It displays the message:

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to install.meteor.com port 443: Connection timed out.
```

The command was successful when I was installing meteor on my computer.

EDIT: The security group setting for inbound allows http and https connection from anywhere.

Comment: Proxy problem I guess...

Comment: I don't use any proxy connection on my local computer and I doubt the server is trying to connect to meteor via a proxy.

Comment: the internet access is not allow or not set properly on that ec2 instance. you need fix it. do you set private VPC or security group to block outbound traffic?

Answer (score 2):

I found the problem after the suggestion from @BMW . I added a https outbound rule to allow any traffic to go to anywhere to the security group.